# Changing the colour of a label, using the label names from a text file. (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, object, label, text-files

I have an array of labels that are supposed to represent seats, when they are clicked they change to green and the names of the green seats are saved to a text file. When the form is loaded again the seats that are booked need to be red, I'm trying to do this by loading the names of the labels from the text file, but it's not currently working. This is my current procedure for loading the names of the booked seats:

```
    ub LoadSeats()
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("Seats.txt") = True Then 'Checks if the seats.txt file is present
        FileReader = New StreamReader("Seats.txt")
        NumOfBookedSeats = FileReader.ReadLine() 'Finds out how many seats have been booked
        For intCounter = 1 To NumOfBookedSeats
            SeatList.Add(FileReader.ReadLine)
            BookedSeat.Name = SeatList(intCounter)
            BookedSeat.BackColor = Color.Red
            BookedSeat.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Next
    Else
        FileWriter = New StreamWriter("Seats.txt")
        FileWriter.WriteLine(0)
        FileWriter.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to describe better about what is not working.

Comment: Please post the portion of code that you use to create the labels (I hope it's not statical)

Comment: is BookedSeat a single label control?

Comment: I don't get it. For simple data storage though i can still recommend io.file.readAllLines and io.file.writeAllLines. The type is a string array and is much harder to muck anything up since its a single line command

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the Controls collection of the form rather than building a separate collection.

To save the labels.  Rather than saving each one that is clicked, change the color, but allow for changes.  Using a common click event handler it would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim clickedlabel = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    If clickedlabel.BackColor = SystemColors.Control Then
        clickedlabel.BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        clickedlabel.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in the click event for a button you would save the state of the labels like this, assuming you've named the labels as "Seat1","Seat2", etc.:

```
    Using sw As New StreamWriter("Seats.txt")
        For Each l As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith("Seat"))
            'if you need to record the green seats do that here.
            sw.WriteLine(l.Name & "," & l.BackColor.ToKnownColor)
        Next
    End Using
```

To load the seats, in the form's load event handler use something like this:

```
    If File.Exists("Seats.txt") Then
        For Each seat As String In File.ReadAllLines("Seats.txt")
            Dim parts = seat.Split(","c)
            If Color.FromKnownColor(CType(parts(1), KnownColor)) = Color.Green Then
                Me.Controls(parts(0)).BackColor = Color.Red
                Me.Controls(parts(0)).Enabled = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
```